# Windows successfully executes ssh but Manjaro does not (publickey)

Tags: windows, ssh, public-key, manjaro

I have a Raspberry Pi and I can login to it using Windows. 
The `.ssh/known_hosts` file is empty. 
However, using Manjaro (a fresh install), I get the following error:

```
pi@raspberrpi: Permission denied (publicKey)
```

This seems to be a pretty common problem on this forum,
but all the other answers either have negative votes or have not worked for me.

This is the pertinent output of `ssh pi@raspberrypi --vv`

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mark/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mark/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mark/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mark/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mark/.ssh/id_xmss
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
pi@raspberrypi: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: What authentication method do you use when logging in from Windows? What authentication method do you want to use when logging in from Manjaro? Are you sure your Manjaro resolves `raspberrypi` to the right address? The server says it only accepts `publickey`; did you expect this? What are "all the other answers" that "have not worked"? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] the question and add information.

Comment: There are half a dozen things that could cause this. If you can, check the syslogs on the raspberrypi to see if `sshd` is logging a reason for the authentication failure.